# C# - Auto-initialization of class's fields via the constructor (manual vs dynamic)

Tags: c#, initialization, field

I have stumbled upon a case which does not affect my design, but will affect future changes of the code and performance, most likely.

My class is the following:

```
public sealed class Commands {
public interface ICommand {
    string commandName { get; set; }
}

public ICommand Maintain;
public ICommand Dispatch;
public ICommand Memorize;
//............//

private class ReckonCommand : ICommand {
    public string commandName { get; set; }

    public ReckonCommand (string name) {
        this.commandName = name;
    }
}

public Commands () {
    Maintain = new ReckonCommand ("Maintain") as ICommand;
    Dispatch = new ReckonCommand ("Dispatch") as ICommand;
    Memorize = new ReckonCommand ("Memorize") as ICommand;
}
```

This approach will require manually initializing each ICommand variable in the Commands class. Thus, it becomes hard to maintain, when the fields become a lot more.

An alternative, dynamic approach is the following:

```
public ICommand Maintain;
public ICommand Dispatch;
public ICommand Memorize;
//............//

private class ReckonCommand : ICommand {
    public float commandName { get; set; }
    //Stuff

}

public Commands () {
    System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] _fields = GetType ().GetFields ();
    for (int i = 0; i < _fields.Length; i++) {
        if (_fields [i].FieldType == typeof(ICommand)) {
            _fields [i].SetValue (this, new ReckonCommand () as ICommand);
        }
    }
}
```

However, the Commands class is expected to be initialized many times (disregard the names, if this hinders you from getting the idea), so the performance loss might be impactful at some point.

Is there an alternative to this specific design that I am using? My concern is to automatically initialize every ICommand field within the constructor of the Commands class.The manual approach is prone to errors which may be too late when uncovered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dynamic approach is perfectly acceptable (we use it all of the time in large scale applications to solve issues just like you have described).

However, you should implement the discovery in a static constructor for the class and store the results in a static collection so that you don't have to perform the reflection every time an instance of the class is created.

Something along the lines of:

```
    private static System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Reflection.FieldInfo> _fields;

    static Commands()
    {
        _fields = new System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Reflection.FieldInfo>();

        var fields = typeof(Commands).GetFields();
        var commandType = typeof(ICommand);

        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            if (field.FieldType == commandType)
            {
                _fields.Add(field);
            }
        }
    }

    public Commands()
    {
        foreach (var field in _fields)
        {
            field.SetValue(this, new ReckonCommand() as ICommand);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Great idea, thank you.
Two things, i) var is known to be slightly slower than direct type declaration; is it because you do not know whether I use the System.Collections.Generic and System.Reflection namespaces or is it perfectly fine in this situation?
ii) Once you have the list of fieldInfo, is the SetValue method as fast as your typical value assignment? I am asking because the ICommand interface will also have a method called Modify(). Should I use the SetValue method or come up with a workaround? Modify() will be used much more frequently than the Commands class initialization.
Cheers

Comment: re var: var is a compile-time concern in which the compiler infers the type of variable from the assignment. It is no slower at runtime than explicitly typing the variable. The reason we use it is to minimize the number of changes required when the data type changes.

Comment: re SetValue: it would be slightly faster and make the application more understandable to use a direct method on the interface rather than SetValue. However, you first need to populate the Commands class with valid instances of ICommand objects, which is what the loop currently does. Once you have an instance, whether created by Command or by the loop, you would then use methods on the ICommand interface to modify that instance (i.e. the Modify method).